# Atom python path not working (using atom-python-run), but works in console

Tags: python, path, atom-editor

I would like to run python scripts from atom. 
However, atom doesn't select the right version of python.

I set my envrionnement variables correctly. If I use path or python command in console it targets my python 3.6 folder location.

```
C:\Users\decau>path
PATH=;C:\Users\decau\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\;C:\Users\decau\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts;C:\Users\decau\AppData\Local\atom\bin

C:\Users\decau>python
Python 3.6.2 (v3.6.2:5fd33b5, Jul  8 2017, 04:14:34) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

But when I use atom and run this script with atom-python-run package:

```
import sys
print(sys.version_info)
```

I got :

```
sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=10, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
```

Why doesn't atom use the correct path?

EDIT : it is really specific to atom-python-run package. With scripts package it works fine, even with atom-runner.

Comment: No, it is really specific to atom-python-run package. With scripts package it works fine, even with atom-runner.

Comment: Apologies - I've retracted my close vote.